# Is it possible to change the position of Bootstrap popovers based on screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items, and each one has a Bootstrap popover associated with it ([docs here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover)). They are initiated like this:

```
$('#my_list li').popover({
   placement: 'left'
});
```

This works, but at small widths the popover is lost from the viewport. I'd like to make the placement conditional based on `$(document).width();`, however I can't see a way to over-ride the initial options (e.g. at at width of around 1000px, switch the placement to 'above').

I've put together a simplified version [at jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/CLVZ4/). Many thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

placement can also take a function as its value. In this function you can return the appropriate value based on width of viewport. For eg.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_list li').popover({
        placement: wheretoplace
    });
});
function wheretoplace(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width<500) return 'bottom';
    return 'left';
}
```

Comment: not working. popover still going under the edge. I'm using BS3

Answer (score 0):

Its change placement from left to top on window smaller than 768

```
placement: function(){return $(window).width()>768 ? "auto left":"auto top";}
```