# Is it possible to change the action of Bootstrap popovers based on screen width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166101/is-it-possible-to-change-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-screen-widt) regarding changing the position of a bootstrap popover depending on the size of the screen.

The answer was great - however I also now want to change the action for popovers (so it's on click for mobile) as well as the location, and am having difficulty re-factoring the code. This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_list li').popover({
        placement: wheretoplace
    });
});

function wheretoplace(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width<500) return 'below';
    return 'left';
}
```

How would I amend the `wheretoplace` function to return two things: the `placement` value along with a `trigger` value? I've got the existing stuff in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/Xhcms/).

**Edit** - I've amended my jsFiddle above to show the complete solution, adding a `click` event to @James' answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to return two values from the function, try assigning them as properties of an object and then return that object.

eg.

```
function wheretoplace(){

    var data = {};    

    var width = window.innerWidth;

    if (width<500)
    { 
        data.placement = 'below';
    }
    else
    {
        data.placement = 'left';
    }

    data.trigger = "myEvent";

    return data;

}
```

Then in the function calling `wheretoplace`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_list li').popover({
        placement: wheretoplace().placement,
        trigger: wheretoplace().trigger
    });
});
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

EDIT: In Response to the comment below:

As with the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgtvq/7/)

By assigning the trigger as "manual" on document ready, you are then able to call `$(element).popover("toggle")` in a click handler which will toggle the appearance of the popover.

Comment: Yes - this goes a long way to a solution, thanks. I've put a version using this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/Dgtvq/); any idea how to get the 'click' functionality using Bootstrap? I'm just passing 'hover' for both right now, as I couldn't get it to work using either focus or manual. [The bootstrap page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) shows the possible values.