# Bootstrap data-placement based on window width

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am looking for a simple way to change my data-placement attribute based on window width for my popover in bootstrap. Below is my current html and jquery code. It works, but the data-placement for my popover does not change as I adjust the window size. Only if I refresh the page with a small window size does it actually work.

```
<a class="arrow" id="arrow" data-toggle="popover" data-content=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" id="glyph"></span></a>

    <script>
    $(window).resize(function(){
   console.log('resize called');
   var width = $(window).width();
   console.log(width);
   if(width < 974){
       $('#glyph').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-right').addClass('glyphicon-menu-down');
       $('#arrow').attr('data-placement','bottom');
       $('.myInfo').css("margin-top", "10px");
       $('.myInfo').css("margin-left", "30px");
   }
   else if(width > 974){
       $('#glyph').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down').addClass('glyphicon-menu-right');
       $('#arrow').attr('data-placement','right');
       $('.myInfo').css("margin-top", "60px");
       $('.myInfo').css("margin-left", "40px");
   }
})

    .resize();
     </script>
```

Everything works except when I change the width of page and click on the popover button again. The data-placement does not change. Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works fine here. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/LnqL7L6o/) What version of `bootstrap` and `jquery` are you using?

Comment: Didn't seem to work when I went to your fiddle. The glyph icon works fine when adjusting window size. When I load a full screen page and click on the popover, it places the content where it should be. Then, when I resize the window and click again, everything works except the jquery line that changes the data-placement attribute. strange..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in) answered by [bchhun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48500/bchhun)

Pass in the placement position as a function:

```
var options = {
    placement: function (context, source) {
        if ($(window).width() < 974) {
            return "bottom";
        } else {
            return "right";
        }
    }
};
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover(options); 
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width < 974){
        $('#glyph').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-right').addClass('glyphicon-menu-down');
        $('.myInfo').css("margin-top", "10px");
        $('.myInfo').css("margin-left", "30px"); 
    }
    else if(width > 974){
        $('#glyph').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down').addClass('glyphicon-menu-right');
        $('.myInfo').css("margin-top", "60px");
        $('.myInfo').css("margin-left", "40px"); 
    }
})
.resize();
```

This [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/AS68s0Xply) shows it working. Hope this helps!