# How can i change the popover data-placement in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the bootstrap popover `data-placement` from bottom to left in jquery based on screen width.

```
<img src="images/user.svg" id="usericon" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="">
```

Jquery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({content: htmlcont,data-placement: left, html: true});
    } else {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({content: htmlcont, html: true});
    }
```

not working for me...how can i do this?

Comment: If you are still having trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `placement` instead of `data-placement`

```
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({content: htmlcont,placement: left, html: true});
    } else {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({content: htmlcont, html: true});
    }
```

That is the property name they use for the [options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)

Also, see [Changing the position of Bootstrap popovers based on the popover's X position in relation to window edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in)