# PopOver auto adjust placement

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am facing an issue with PopOver. I want it to auto adjust at all positions. If it doesn't find space on right side it opens at left. But I want it to do the same thing for top/bottom. i.e if it doesn't find space at top it should open at bottom and vice versa. Isn't there any way I can do it for all sides?

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'auto right'
    })
```

The **HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="popover" class="hlpicon" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-content="This will open a popover" data-original-title="" title=""></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `placement` option as either a **string** or a **function returning a string**:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: function (context, source) {
        var position = $(source).position();

        if (position.left > 515) {
            return "left";
        }

        if (position.left < 515) {
            return "right";
        }

        if (position.top < 110){
            return "bottom";
        }

        return "top";
    }
});
```

For context, the source of this code is [Changing the position of Bootstrap popovers based on the popover's X position in relation to window edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in) (which declares attribution to be not required - just adding this as a resource).

Comment: Could you please tell me what is `context` and `source`? Also check my updated question, I have added the HTML as well(in case its useful)

Comment: Context was an example. Source is used to pass the function.

Comment: In your HTML, you have the data-trigger set to hover, but in the jQuery you have the trigger set to manual. You will want to remove one of those, depending on if you want the popover to show when hovered over, or clicked on

Comment: You have taken this 515 and 110 values arbitrarily?

Comment: @Multistack source of magic numbers is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in

Answer (score 0):

The chosen solution was a good start but not enought in my case. I had to replace **`position.top`** by **`$(source).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()`**

This is my working solution

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                        [...]
                        placement: function (context, source) {

                            if ($(source).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < 280) {
                                return "bottom";
                            }

                            return "top";
                        }
                    }).popover('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this will be help full in case:

```
$element.popover("update")
```

it will update your popover easily.