# screen Viewport using $(window).height()

Tags: jquery, html, viewport

I am calculating the size of my Viewport using `$(window).height()` which returns `339`
Now I want to break my screen into three parts. Top,middle,bottom. I want to know How can I calculate this knowing that the Screen Height returned is 339.

I want to know how many `px` out of the total(339) would be covered in 20% of top,60% of middle and 20% of bottom. How would I calculate this? Can anybody help me with this?Also, is my approach right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The math is really simple:

> (winH = 339)
>
> 0.6 * winH = middleH       (203.4)
>     0.2 * winH = topH, botH    (67.8)

But hey! Why do you need jQuery?

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

#top,
#bot{
  height:20vh;
  background:#0bf;
}
#mid{
  height:60vh;
  background:#f0b;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"> top </div>
<div id="mid"> mid </div>
<div id="bot"> bot </div>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to store top,middle,bottom pixels values in jquery variables. I have an HTML element and I want to compare its `position` with these variables. For example, `if($(element).position < top)`

Comment: So if my element lies in the bottom area, how would I know?

Comment: Basically, for this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485342/popover-auto-adjust-placement I am trying to get the top, middle and bottom areas of my screen so I can compare as to where my element lies