# Position bootstrap popover with 20px 'margin' to window edge

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

I've been asked if I can get our bootstrap popovers avoiding the left and right window edges. I've been reading the bootstrap site, the tether site and SO..
[Changing the position of Bootstrap popovers based on the popover's X position in relation to window edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in)
...but so far haven't found something that can set a **minimum pixel distance** to the right and left edges of the window.
I've tried to get the .css('left') value of the open popover, but all I'm getting is 'undefined'.

I have a link with an onclick attribute that points to the following function (which, other than the positioning issue, initialises the popover correctly)...

```
function emailCertificateClick(e) {
    var emailLink = $(e);
    var attemptId = $(emailLink).attr("data-attempt-id");
    var url = "/CL/MyTraining/EmailCertificate/?attemptId=" + attemptId;
    $.get(url, function (data) {

        var popover = emailLink.data('bs.popover');

        if (data && data.Result == "Success") {
            popover.options.title = '<div class="certificate-email-success-popover-title">';
            popover.options.title += '<span class="fa fa-check">';
            popover.options.title += '<svg>';
            popover.options.title += '<use xlink:href="/Areas/CL/Content/app/images/icons/icon-svg-defs.svg#fa-check"></use>';
            popover.options.title += '</svg>';
            popover.options.title += certificateSentSuccessfullyTitle;
            popover.options.title += '</span>';
            popover.options.title += '</div >';
            popover.options.content = certificateSentSuccessfullyMessage + ' <b>' + data.Email + '</b>';
        }
        else {
            popover.options.title = '<div class="certificate-email-error-popover-title">';
            popover.options.title += '<span class="fa fa-times">';
            popover.options.title += '<svg>';
            popover.options.title += '<use xlink:href="/Areas/CL/Content/app/images/icons/icon-svg-defs.svg#fa-times"></use>';
            popover.options.title += '</svg>';
            popover.options.title += certificateEmailFailedTitle;
            popover.options.title += '</span>';
            popover.options.title += '</div >';
            popover.options.content = certificateEmailFailedMessage;
        }

        popover.show();
        var $popover = $('.my-training-certficate .popover'); 
        console.log("$popover = " + $popover); // [object Object]
        var popoverXPosition = $popover.css('left');
        console.log("popoverXPosition = " + popoverXPosition); // undefined       
    });

    return false;
}
```

Inspecting the open popover in dev tools, I can see that the popover does, indeed, have its css('left') set to '-165px'. I have not been able to find how or where that is set.

Is there a best practise, non-workaround way to prevent bootstrap popovers from touching the window edges? Cheers.