# Bootstrap popover placement auto, body + header placement

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-popover

this is my last resort, as I was looking at this question:

[Changing the position of Bootstrap popovers based on the popover's X position in relation to window edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in)

And couldn't find a solution to my problem, currently I have the popovers triggered by this code:

```js
var popOverSettings = {
  selector: '[data-toggle=popover]',
  viewport: {
    selector: '.container',
    padding: 80
  },
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'auto top',
  html: true,
  container: 'body',
  animation: false,
  delay: {
    show: 50,
    hide: 100
  }
};

$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
```

When the popover reaches the body maximum top, it automatically pushes it down, but I want that it takes the height of the header too, is there any way to specify pixels to the top placement? something like `placement: 'auto top' + 50`, because this is what happens:

[image: Current problem]

Thanks in advance.