# Bootstrap 4 tooltip/popover using auto placement as a fallback (two placement values)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, position

Bootstrap 3 used to provide functionality to support data-placement="left auto" where it would show the tip on the left if there was enough room, otherwise it would calculate an auto placement.

Bootstrap 4 does not support two placement values, you can only provide left OR auto.

Any idea on how to achieve this in BS4?  I was working off [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081924/166231) along with looking at BS3.js source, but I am getting stuck trying to determine the 'current height/width' of the tooltip to be displayed and from BS3.js, what to use as the 'viewport' (I'm assuming the `window` object?)

Comment: You may take a look to this  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2sqc109/3/),

Comment: The `fallbackPlacement` option from [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/tooltips/#options) clearly isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8wmsgxek/

Comment: Kludge workaround to fallbackPlacement not working in bs4: `placement: (document.body.clientWidth < 440) ? "bottom" : "left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...even thought Bootstrap 4/popper doesn't support the 'dual' placement values that Bootstrap 3 did, it seems to work as thought 'auto' was appended.  i.e. if your placement is only 'left' but there isn't room, BS4/popper already moves it to make sure it displays.  So I guess this is a non-issue.  Surprised they even support an 'auto' placement.  Seems like developers should always provide their 'desired' location and let popper 'fix' it if the viewport doesn't support it :)