# Change placement of bootstrap 2.1.1 tooltip on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a total noob and just spend 3 hours googling & trying but couldnt figure it out. I have this

```
<span class="payshiptiptop tooltips">
 <a href="#" id="payshiptiptop" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="<div  class='paymentmethods'></div>" data-html="true">
  GRATIS Versand
 </a>
</span>
```

but if it is on mobile, it should be placed on top.
As 2.1.1 does not support auto right, I tried several codes from stackoverflow e.g. [Is it possible to change the position of Bootstrap popovers based on screen width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166101/is-it-possible-to-change-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-screen-widt) and [Changing the position of Bootstrap popovers based on the popover's X position in relation to window edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in) as well as a lot of others.

I guess this is the way to go:

```
<script>
var options = {
    placement: function (context, source) {
        var position = $(source).position();

        if (position.left < 480) {
            return "top";
        }

        return "right";
    }
};
$("#payshiptiptop").popover(options);
</script>
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me & tell me what I have to post in my php file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a CSS based solution, here is the markup for the popover:

```
<div class="yourContainingClass">
  <div class="popover fade top in" role="tooltip">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="popover-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Providing you gave it a wraping class, do whatever CSS in a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .yourContainingClass .popover {

  }
  .yourContainingClass .popover-title {

  }
  .yourContainingClass .popover-content {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need to change is the data-placement which defines the absolute position of the tooltip using js. It is impossible to get the results using css, bc I cannot calculate the absolute position values in it.