# Popover positioning not working based on Position and offset

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have trying to position my popover based on the left and right position of a div but I am not able to do that.

The bottom image shows the problem I am facing

[image: Popover going behind the right div]

The code I have for the popover is as follows:

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'hover',
                trigger: 'click',
                placement: 'right',
                template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title" style="display:none;"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
                content: function () { return '<img style="width:250px" src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />'; }
            });
```

I tried using the placement as a function as suggested in the following links:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in‏](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956958/changing-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-the-popovers-x-position-in%E2%80%8F)

[Is it possible to change the position of Bootstrap popovers based on screen width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166101/is-it-possible-to-change-the-position-of-bootstrap-popovers-based-on-screen-widt)

These didn't work.

**IMPORTANT** The image shown to you is in a fancybox

Comment: How about using placement `auto` or `auto right`?

Comment: what kind of fancybox? iframe?

Comment: @DavidG Placement auto right is also not working have tried it. It is showing all the elements on the left and auto left showing all the elements to the right.

Comment: @Julo0sS Iframe Fancybox

Comment: tbh, I don't understand exactly what you're tryin to do... can you tell us, with details, what has to be displayed, & where... thx

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: your popover code is into the "global file" or into the "iframe" file code? YES : Fiddle would be great to see what's happening....

Comment: @dreamweiver http://www.swiss-nl.performamanager.nl/boxsprings/van-der-valk-hotelboxspring-ariana
Open this link
Click on the six points mentioned on the right 1. Matt .......
A fancy box would open... Click the boxes untill you reach step 3.

At step 3 If you hover over the colors you will find the behaviour I am asking for.

Comment: can you tell me which is the script, which has the above `popover` js script from your site, im not able to find it. `productDetails.js` script has the above code but its commented

Comment: @dreamweiver It is in the partial view for the fancybox and that has been referenced in the partial and not in the view you are checking.

boxspringQuickview.js